# Release COM interface without the knowledge of coclass

Tags: c#, com, interface, interop

I have a C# client that consumes interfaces from a native C++ COM server dll. The DLL implements 4 interfaces. These 4 interfaces are implemented by 4 coclasses in the DLL. But only 1 coclass is exposed to the client. Interfaces 2,3,4 are returned to the client by one of the methods in interfaces 1.

C++ COM server:

```
interface IFace1: IUnknown{
HRESULT CreateOtherInterface([in] REFIID iidFace, [out, iid_is(iidFace)] void** ppOut);
};

coclass ClassIFace1
{
    [default] interface IFace1;
};
```

C# Client:

```
ClassIFace1 Face1Obj = new ClassIFace1();

IFace1 Face1Ctrl = (IFace1)Face1Obj; 

IFace2 Face2Ctrl = null;
IntPtr Face2IntPtr = new IntPtr();

Face1Ctrl.CreateOtherInterface(Face2Guid, out Face2IntPtr);
Face2Ctrl = (IFace2)Mashal.PtrToStructure(Face2IntPtr);

//Consume Face2Ctrl

if(Face1Obj != null)
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face1Obj);
}
```

As IFace2, IFace3 and IFace4 does not share the same coclass as IFace1, I suspect the Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face1Obj) line will only destruct ClassIFace1 object but not ClassIFace2, ClassIFace3, ClassIFace4 objects and results in memory leaks. Is there any way to solve this? Or the Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face1Obj) actually destroy other COM objects as well?

Comment: Perhaps I should be more specific here. The COM server will talk to devices. And different devices expose a different set of features. Each feature is implemented as a feature interface such as IFace2, IFace3 etc. Clients just need to give the iid of the feature that they are interested in, the COM server will return the feature interface if the device supports it, otherwise the call will fail.

Comment: Client has no knowledge whether IFace2, IFace3 etc are implemented with the same coclass as IFace1 or not (actually they are different coclasses), and neither do they care. They just get all the feature interfaces from IFace1, and release the feature interfaces individually after finish with them. This method works great for C++ clients for all these years, until we need to implement a C# client to talk to the COM server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what Hans said, `CreateOtherInterface` looks very odd.  Normally, you don't need to create it by yourself.  All you need to do is to make sure client can access all four coclasses.  Then, the `Activator.CreateInstance` or the native `CoCreateInstance` will do the right thing for you.  Another choice is to expose one single coclass and have that single coclass supporting all four interfaces.

However, since you mentioned that only 1 coclass is exposed to client, I am imagining there are some strange reasons that the TLB file consumed by the client doesn't see the other 3 coclasses or the other 3 coclasses were not registered properly but discovered by the first coclass in some proprietary ways.  I am also assuming that you cannot modify server side implementation.

Given all these assumption, here is my answer.  The reference counts are maintained within the 4 coclasses independently.  So, releasing the reference on the first coclass won't decrement the reference counts in the other three coclasses.

There are some more things you need to pay attention.  You are using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face1Obj)` to release the first coclass.  You can do that because the first coclass was wrapped by a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW).  Like what Martin said, even if you don't call the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`, .NET runtime will do it for you when garbabge collection occurs.

However, *Face2Ctrl* is obtained differently.  It's not wrapped by a RCW.  You are treating the returned pointer as a structure directly.  This doesn't sound right to me because you may have issues on memory alignment and data marshalling.  What you want to do might be calling `Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown` which will return a RCW for you.  Once you get your RCW, you can call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` to release your RCW in timely manner.

If the implementation of `CreateOtherInterface` is like `QueryInterface`, which always `AddRef` on the returned interface, you should call `Marshal.Release` on the returned interface once you are done with *Face2Obj*.  `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` is not enough because it just releasees the reference count added by the RCW but in this case, you need more one call on `IUnknown.Release`

Comment: For coclasses, when I have 40+ interfaces, it is really not very nice to ask the client to access all 40+ coclasses. Besides, the COM server would need to do some init code and pass some general information to all 40+ coclass, this is currently done in coclassFace1 and when CreateOtherInterface() is called, coclassFace1 will create other coclasses and pass the init information to the class before returning the new interface pointer to the client.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting my client to convert IFace2 interface to IntPtr then use `Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown` and `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face2Obj)` to release. Is this correct? And then use `Marshal.Release()` to release the IntPtr of IFace2? But shouldn't the Face2 COM object has been fully released by `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face2Obj)` already? Unless `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face2Obj)` only release the RCW but not the underlying native COM object.......? But, this is a good advice, I should definitely try it out.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

It is the normal behaviour with COM objects, that you access them exclusively by their interfaces. The coclass is necessary only to create new instances of a COM object, you do not directly access the coclass. So i suspect your example should look like that:

```
IFace1 face1Ctrl = new ClassIFace1();
```

The method `CreateOtherInterface()` looks a bit strange to me, it has the same signature as a `QueryInterface()`, so i assume it should do the same thing (i'm not familiar with C++):

```
IFace2 face2Ctrl;
face1Ctrl.CreateOtherInterface(IFace2, out face2Ctrl);
```

I think this should do, just try it out. If it where the normal QueryInterface method, you should be able to get the interface like that:

```
IFace2 face2Ctrl = face1Ctrl as IFace2;
```

COM objects are reference counted, they are released as soon as you destroy the last reference to the interface. As soon as the garbage collector destroys your variables with references to the COM object, the COM object will release itself. That can be a problem in C#, because you have to wait on the garbage collector and cannot determine the order of releasing. If you need to release a COM object at a given moment, you can use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`, but normally you just wait on the garbage collector to decrement the reference counter.

As long as you do not know the implementation of the COM object, you do not know, if each interface has it's own coclass, or if one coclass implements several interfaces. You should not need this knowledge, when you use the COM object. The query interface could create a new coclass and return it's interface, or it could return itself and increase the reference counter.

Comment: Yes, CreateOtherInterface() works exactly like QueryInterface(): pass in the interface iid, it will return the interface pointer. The difference is QueryInterface() only returns interfaces that are impelmented on the same coclass (unless you overwrite QueryInterface() yourself), but CreateOtherInterface() can return any interfaces regardless whether they are implemented on the same coclass or not. I don't quite understand the last part of your comment, are you suggesting I should wait for the garbage collector to decrement the ref count for CoclassFace2, CoclassFace3?

Comment: @Angela Yan - Yes you can wait for the garbage collector. When you call `CreateOtherInterface()`, in your case it will create a new instance of class `ClassIFace2` and will return an interface `IFace2` to this object. With this interface you increase the reference counter to the object. Now you hold a reference to the first object via IFace1, and another reference to the second object via IFace2. As soon as the garbage collector collects the variable to IFace1, the first object is released, when it collects the variable to IFace2, the second object is released.

Comment: @Angela Yan - The comment above assumes, that you do **not** use fancy things like `IntPtr` or the `Marshal` class, this should not be necessary, and i would avoid it if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the info. But what if I want to deterministically terminate the COM server instead of waiting for Garbage collector, is there any way to do it? And currently `CreateOtherInterface()` 's 2nd param is an IntPtr (for returning the interface) based on what I can see in the C# project's object browser after I add the COM server's typelib as reference to the C# project.

Comment: If you need a deterministic behaviour, you can either force the garbage collector to do it's work, or if you need a given order, you can call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` or even `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject()`. If you do so, you have to make sure, that the variables are not used afterwards in your code. To the intPtr: The method looks scary, because it cannot know, what interface you will request, but DotNet takes care that you can just pass a variable of the required interface (see the second code example).

Comment: The "normal" way would be, that you implement the logic of creating the other object in `QueryInterface()`, then you could just use the `as` operator to get the other interface (which internally calls QueryInterface).

Comment: I could do the creating other objects in `QueryInterface()` way, but it still leaves me the same question of how to ensure other objects will be destroyed since `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` only frees the first COM object `ClassFace1`.

Comment: You call it once with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(face1Ctrl)`, this will decrease the reference counter of the first COM object to 0, and the COM object will release itself, then you call it with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(face2Ctrl)`, this will set the counter of the second COM object to 0 and therefore release the second COM object. The same would happen when the garbage collector would destroy the two variables face1Ctrl and face2Ctrl. Since the COM object is your own code, you can log Addref and Release, so you can test the correct releasing.

Comment: I have tried `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(face2Ctrl)`. But it doesn't trigger my face2coclass object to go into `FinalRelease()`. Instead, I followed your earlier suggestion and tried `Marshal.Release(Face2IntPtr)`. I have to call it 3 times since the way the C# client get the interface to increase 3 refCount on Face2 interface. And after that I call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(face1Obj)`, and --- both Face1 ojbect and Face2 object will get `FinalReleasea()`.

Comment: (Face1 object also holds 1 RefCount to Face2 object that is why Face2 object will only reach RefCount 0 when Face1 object is destroyed as well). Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Ahh yes, COM objects that hold references to each other, can be a tricky thing. The worst is, when A holds a reference to B, and B holds a reference to A, this would make it impossible to release the objects in an appropriate way.

Comment: The current case is A (Face1 object) holds a reference to B (Face2 object)), but B does not hold a reference to A.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, there is some mistakes on how to get the interface. Here is the complete solution for the C# client:

```
//======Create IFace1 and IFace2 interface===============
Type consoleType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Face1CoCLSID);
Object Face1Obj = Activator.CreateInstance(consoleType);
IFace1 Face1Ctrl = (IFace1)Face1Obj;

Guid IFace2Guid = typeof(IFace2).GUID;
IntPtr Face2IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

//Face2 object's ref count will go up 1
Face1Ctrl.CreateOtherInterface(Face2Guid, out Face2IntPtr); 

//Face2 object's ref count will go up 2. One by "GetObjectForIUnknown()" 
//and one by "as", since the "as" will trigger .Net to call QueryInterface()
IFace2 Face2Ctrl = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(Face2IntPtr) as IFace2; 

//=============Consume Face2Ctrl=========================

//======Destroy IFace1 and IFace2 interface===============

if (Face2Ctrl != null)
{
//Release 3 times as there were 3 RefCount obtained.

    Marshal.Release(Face2IntPtr);
    Marshal.Release(Face2IntPtr);
    Marshal.Release(Face2IntPtr);
    Face2Ctrl = null;     
}

if(Face1Obj != null)
{
//both Face1 object and Face2 object will get FinalRelease() after
//this line.
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Face1Obj); 
    Face1Obj = null;
}
```